# suitable mvc for website

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks

what's the good MVC Framework to develop a website like stackoverflow(question answer website) ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself, which research have you put in before asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) is the latest incarntion from microsoft. If you're familiar with .NET thats probably a good one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want a MVC Web framework, you can try with Ruby on Rails, seems it is a full MVC framework which is also easy to learn and fast for developing.

If your target is to support a site with the characteristics of stacoverflow (I mean, the amount of users, for instance), I think you can go with something more "stable" and with less resources comsuption, like cakePHP, which is basically a PHP port of Rails, bringing you the best of both worlds (Ruby and PHP).

If you are more a Microsoft person, you can try ASP.NET MVC or Monorail (which is inspired by rails but has nothing to do with Mono nor Rails).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Shapado](http://shapado.com)?  It is a stackoverflow clone that is built with Ruby on Rails.  You can checkout their source code [here](http://gitorious.org/shapado).